# get the initial value of a form field as a string in template

Tags: python, django, forms

If I have set an initial values for the form which I am passing with the help of kargs.
like this

```
kwargs['initial'] = initial_data
        super(JobAdReplyForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)`
```

All is well and when I am trying to get the form fields in template, I am getting them using `form.field_name` with the initial value. Now what I want to do is to get the `initial` value of a particular field in the template only as a string so that I can print it in template itself.

some thing like `form.field_name.initial`

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using django 1.3 or greater you should be able to use
`{{ form.field_name.value }}` in your template.